# Deleting in OneToMany Relationship

Tags: java, entity-framework, hibernate, jpa

I have created two entities Employee and Position. I have unidirectional OneToMany Relationship from Employee to Position i.e. Position entity contains records of employee past data. I have employee class as

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "EMPLOYEES")
@Audited
public class Employee extends BaseEntity {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 9025203354200600861L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "EMPLOYEE_NUMBER")
    private Integer employeeNumber; 

    @OneToMany(targetEntity = Position.class, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinTable(joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="EMPLOYEE_ID"),
              inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="POSITION_ID"))
    private List<Position> position;

public List<Position> getPosition() {
    return position;
}

public void setPosition(List<Position> position) {
    this.position = position;
}
}
```

I have delete function as with dao injection:

```
 @Inject 
    PositionDao positionDao;

/.../
public void deletePosition(){
        positionDao.delete(positionDao.getEntityById(3));
    }
```

The delete function uses entity manager remove function as:

```
  public void delete(T t) {
    em.remove(t);
}
```

Since the relation is one to many, I must be able to delete the from position entity. But when I try to perform delete it gives exception as:

```
The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "FK1fygqmvwtna26i9cisuavevo". The conflict occurred in database "Research", table "dbo.EMPLOYEES_POSITIONS", column 'POSITION_ID'.
```

[image: Employee Table]

[image: Position Table]

[image: Intermediate Table Generated from the relationship]

Employee Table 
Position Table
Intermediate Table Generated from the relationship

Comment: Post the code of the delete method. of positionDao

Comment: I have used entityManager remove functionality